# Generating a MySQL query

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to create a function to return a DataTable with the results of a MySQL query where the program doesn't know the names of the queried columns until run-time.

How can I improve the readability of this function? Is concatenating strings like this an appropriate way to generate MySQL queries?

```
public static DataTable Entries(string db, string user, string dtStart, string dtEnd = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", List<string[]> column = null)
    {
            string mysqlTimestamp = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
            string cmd = string.Format("SELECT * FROM `{0}`.`{1}_table` WHERE ", db, user);

            if (dtEnd != mysqlTimestamp)
            {
                cmd += "`Timestamp` >= @dtStart AND `Timestamp` <= @dtEnd";
            }
            else {
                cmd += "`Timestamp` = @dtStart";
            }

            if (column != null)
            {
                cmd += " AND";

                string colQuery = " `{0}` = @{0}";
                for (int i = 0; i < column.Count(); i++)
                {
                    cmd += string.Format(colQuery, column[i]);
                    if (i != column.Count() - 1) { cmd += " AND"; }
                }
            }

            var data = new DataSet();
            using (var MySql = Query.Connection(Session.Current.Username, Session.Current.Database))
            {
                MySql.Open();
                using (var MySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(cmd, MySql))
                {
                    MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtstart", dtStart);
                    MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtEnd", dtEnd);
                    if (column != null)
                    {
                        foreach (string[] col in column)
                        {
                            MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + col[0], col[1]);
                        }
                    }

                    using (var Adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(MySqlCmd))
                    {
                        Adapter.Fill(data);
                    }
                }
            }
            return data.Tables[0];
        }
    }
```

Results in the string:

```
SELECT * FROM `db`.`someuser_table` WHERE `Timestamp` >= @dtStart AND `Timestamp` <= @dtEnd AND `Column1` = @Column1 AND `Column3` = @Column3
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `db`.`someuser_table` WHERE `Timestamp` >= @dtStart
```

and anything in between.

Answer (score 1):

- To improve readability you should use proper naming conversions.
- From the given code what i can understand that the input parameter `user` is for constructing the table name, that means all your table looks like `someName_table`(i'm not sure), if so `user` is not a good name for that variable, let me rename them as `queryOnTable`.
- Another thing i have noticed is that `Timestamp` will be a common column for all your tables.(me too assume so or else we have to consider that too).
- Here in your case you are specifying the database name as well as the
  current user of the database in the connection using `var MySql =
  Query.Connection(Session.Current.Username, Session.Current.Database)`
  so you need not be specified them in the executable query. Or else
  you can use the input parameters `db` and `user`(if the above point is false) can be used to create the connection(if connection string change dynamically). This may help you to reduce the complex formatting of the select statement.
- Here the given snippet will always select the whole data ( select `*`
  ) from the given table, This will not be a good choice, always
  collect the data which you want. I i prefer you to use another input
  array to the function that specifies the required fields.
- [This article](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) says that `.Parameters.Add()` is better choice that `.Parameters.AddWithValue()` So we can prefer that here by changing the last parameter `List<string[]> column` to something like `List<myQueryParameter>`.

where `myQueryParameter` is defined as:

```
public class myQueryParameter
    {
        public MySqlDbType  paramType { get; set; }
        public string paramValue { get; set; }
    }
```

- I suggest you to include an additional parameter called `additionalClause` which can be used for specifying clauses like Group by, order by etc.
- Now the query building; Many article available in the various sites stated that `StringBuilder` is the best option for concatenating the string when the concatenations are more than 1000, where as `String.Join()` is even more efficient than `StringBuilder` if concatenations are less than 1000. `+` and `String.Concat()` are less efficient than these two.

Now consider the modified method:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(string queryOnTable,
                                    string dtStart,
                                    string dtEnd = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                    List<string> reqColumns = null,
                                    List<myQueryParameter> conditionalParams = null),
                                    string additionalClause="")
    {
        if (reqColumns == null) { reqColumns = new List<string>() { "*" }; } // select all columns if not specified

        string mysqlTimestamp = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

        StringBuilder sqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        sqlQueryBuilder.Append("SELECT ");
        sqlQueryBuilder.Append(String.Join(",", reqColumns));
        sqlQueryBuilder.Append(String.Format(" FROM {0} WHERE ", queryOnTable));

        if (dtEnd != mysqlTimestamp)
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.Append("`Timestamp` >= @dtStart AND `Timestamp` <= @dtEnd");
        }
        else
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.Append("`Timestamp` = @dtStart");
        }

        if (conditionalParams != null)
        {
            foreach (myQueryParameter param in conditionalParams)
            {
                sqlQueryBuilder.Append(String.Format(" AND `{0}` = @{0}", param.param));
            }
        }

        if (additionalClause != "")
            sqlQueryBuilder.Append(additionalClause); 

        var data = new DataSet();
        using (var MySql = new MySqlConnection("Query.Connection(Session.Current.Username, Session.Current.Database)"))
        {
            MySql.Open();
            using (var MySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQueryBuilder.ToString(), MySql))
            {
                MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtstart", dtStart);
                MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtEnd", dtEnd);
                if (conditionalParams != null)
                {
                    foreach (myQueryParameter condition in conditionalParams)
                    {
                        MySqlCmd.Parameters.Add(String.Format("@{0}",condition.param),condition.paramType).Value = condition.paramValue; 
                    }
                }
                using (var Adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(MySqlCmd))
                {
                    Adapter.Fill(data);
                }
            }
        }
        return data.Tables[0];
    }
```

Before going to the usage example let me define a table; Let `user_data` is the table having columns as follows:

```
Column Name  | DataType
user_id          VarChar
user_name        VarChar
int_field        Int32
text_field1       Text
text_field2       Text
text_field3       Text
Timestamp         DateTime
```

We can call the `GetDataTable()` method as like the following:

```
// Creating input parameters
List<string> reqcolumns = new List<string>() { "user_name", "int_field", "text_field1", "text_field2","text_field3" };
List<myQueryParameter> parameters = new List<myQueryParameter>();
parameters.Add(new myQueryParameter() { param = "user_id", paramType = MySqlDbType.VarChar, paramValue = "USR001" });
parameters.Add(new myQueryParameter() { param = "int_field", paramType = MySqlDbType.Int32, paramValue = "12" });
parameters.Add(new myQueryParameter() { param = "user_name", paramType = MySqlDbType.VarChar, paramValue = "un-luckey" });

//Calling the method
var dt = GetDataTable("user_data",
                      "2014-02-15 00:00:00",
                      "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                      reqcolumns, parameters,
                      " Order by Timestamp");
```

Which will creates the query as like the following:

> SELECT user_name,int_field,text_field1,text_field2,text_field3 FROM
>   user_data WHERE Timestamp = @dtStart AND user_id = @user_id AND
>   int_field = @int_field AND user_name = @user_name Order by Timestamp